# Project in IntelliJ will change compile language level to 1.5 automatically

Tags: intellij-idea

I am sure why Project in IntelliJ will change compile language level to 1.5 automatically even after I change to 1.8 manually. Might be it is after I execute mvn build. If so, if there any way to keep it using 1.8 forever?

Comment: You can specify language levels in maven, in your pom, that should help. Use the maven compiler plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html